# ¿Cómo puedo darle espaciado a un elemento html con css?

Tags: css, html5

Tengo problemas al tratar de darle un espacio a un elemento `HTML` que se encuentra dentro de un menú.

Lo que quiero hacer es darle un margen de 10px a la derecha y 10px a la izquierda a un icono dentro, pero no logro llegarle al elemento o no se aplican los cambios.

menú lateral izquierdo:

```css
.left-navbar {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: $bgcolor;
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    li {
      opacity: 0.8;
      margin: 0px;
      i {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    }
  }
}

.space-i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-menu">
    <div class="left-navbar">
      <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/60" alt="" srcset="" />
      </div>
      <div class="full-name">
        <p>Ing. Maria G</p>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <button>Link 1</button>
        <button>Link 2</button>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users space-i">Employees</i></a>
        </li>    
    </div>
  </div>
```

Creé una clase `CSS` llamada "space-i" la cual aplico a la clase del icono pero esta no se ve afectada, Por qué?

```
<a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users space-i">Employees</i></a>
```

El icono se ve pegado al texto "employee" de izquierda a derecha, y es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Usa: Padding:10 px

Comment: Maria G, cuando se trata de iconfonts el primer espacio cuenta, esto debería de funcionarte `<a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users space-i"></i> Employees</a>`  La palabra `Employees` fuera del html del icono.

Comment: Puedes probar con word-spacing :y line-height. Por cierto, creo que sería mejor usar la clase dentro del li. Además, es recomendable usar <em> en lugar de <i>. Un saludo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como funciona los iconos de fontawesome.

1. con "fas" declaras la tipografía y otras propiedades.
2. con "fa-users" declaras el icono a usar.

En tu archivo HTML la sintaxis para declarar el icono es así.

```
<a href="" class="link"><i class="fas fa-users">Employees</i></a>
```

En el archivo CSS proporcionado por Fontawesome el icono esta declarado así.

```
.fa-users:before { content: "\f0c0";}
```

Entonces para poder darle un espaciado a tu icono puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
.space-i::before { margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px;}
```